# IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before

Tags: android

I do not understand why I can not start a thread, and how can I do this?

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runUpdatePreOrders, 0,
                timeRepeat, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

private Runnable runUpdatePreOrders = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized  (runUpdatePreOrders) {

                    try {
                        if (pause) wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                new UpdateOrders(min_price, listener).execute();
                Log.e("UpdateBrodcast", "StartPreOrder");
            }
        }
    };

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (pause) {
            runUpdatePreOrders.notify();   // this IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before
        }

        pause = false;


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      synchronized  (runUpdatePreOrders) {

                try {
                    if (pause) runUpdatePreOrders.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            new UpdateOrders(min_price, listener).execute();
            Log.e("UpdateBrodcast", "StartPreOrder");
        }
    }
```

if you sync on a object you should call wait and notify on the same object

EDIT

```
  if (pause) {
      synchronized  (runUpdatePreOrders) {
            runUpdatePreOrders.notify();   // this IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before
       }
   }
```

Comment: if (pause) runUpdatePreOrders.wait(); you call wait not on runUpdatePreOrders but on "this" object

Comment: =( I try different ways does but not work, this.wait(); and then  runUpdatePreOrders.notify(); correctly?

Comment: you have to use runUpdatePreOrders.wait();

Comment: i just have one doubt remaining after acknowledging your answer,  do we have to lock the thread object in both the parts ie. befor calling wait on that thread object and before calling notify on that thread object

Comment: you have to use the same lock object.